# jQuery Image Preload, Relative to Current Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i wish to achieve, is a jQuery image preloader, that loads a different image based on the current document. The way i want to achieve this is through a jQuery script similar to:
documentname-extension (ie .php .html) + _definable imagename and extension.
So example, if the current document is index.php and you define the imagename as _kids.jpg the preloader will load the file index_kids.jpg, if you were in the document market.php, the preloader would load the file market_kids.jpg.
I am not very skilled in jQuery, i have some ideas how to make a script to do this but nothing really organised. I was hoping someone could help me.

Comment: This seems to be more of a PHP-related question then jQuery. Or is there a specific reason as to why you want to do this client-side?

Comment: @alex I figure you probably have an answer.

Comment: @Marcus .php is just a possible extension on the file, all i was saying is if the document is .html or .php i want it to not get confused either way.

Comment: I won't see the mention unless I have interacted on the post previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP, you could do it like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "<?php echo substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos(__FILE__, '.')); ?>_kids.jpg";
```

For a javascript-only solution that will behave just like the example above:

```
var href = document.location.href;
var filename = href.substring(href.lastIndexOf('/')+1, href.lastIndexOf('.'));
img.src = filename+"_kids.jpg";
```

Comment: @Marcus so will this do what i mentioned earlier "out of the box" so to speak. I mean looking at it it seams that it will if i put it in a function() wrapper, is this correct?

Comment: @Marcus Hmm it doesn't seem to be working. My Testing Server is here http://www.letsmine.info/Sundalah If you want to check it yourself.

Comment: @Marcus wait give me a sec i forgot to modify something.

Comment: @Marcus Finally if i wanted to preload more then one image this code will get messy? Anyway more efficient ways of doing it for more then one image? Still Doesn't work but.

Comment: @Jason, I added a javascript-only solution. Easiest way to use it for adding multiple images would be to throw it into it's own function with the suffix as a passable argument.

Comment: @Marcus Your PHP example didn't work for me http://www.letsmine.info/Sundalah All the pages are .php, so its not that. Testing your pure javascript now.

Comment: @Jason you'd have to update the source of the image with the path to where your images are stored, if you haven't done that already ;)

Comment: @Marcus I just understood what you meant. Where in your code would i add the path to where the image is. I had to go out which is why i havent commented in 3 hours.

Comment: @Marcus Isn't preloading because the image is in javascript not your fault.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the current file's filename without the extension, try this...

```
echo basename(__FILE__, '.' . pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/GmzYawAD).

Comment: @alex how would you get it without the extension?

Comment: @Jason The PHP tags were implied.

Comment: @alex I mean your CodePad version the php start <? doesn't end ?> but.

Comment: @Jason The trailing `?>` is optional if at the end of the file. In fact, when including files strictly PHP code, the `?>` is [not recommended](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html#coding-standard.php-file-formatting.general).

Comment: +1 for the proper way, compared to my hackish PHP solution :)